# Use JTransfo to convert lists

Tags: java, rest, jersey

Inside a REST Application I use *JTransfo* to convert domain to transfer objects:

```
@Override
public TestTo find(int id) {
    TestDo t = dao.find(id);

    JTransfo jTransfo = new JTransfoImpl();

    TestTo to = jTransfo.convert(l, new TestToImpl());

    return to;
}
```

Sometime I have to convert lists:

```
@Override
public List<TestTo> find(...) {
    List<TestDo> list = dao.find(...);

    List<TestTo> to = new ArrayList<TestTo>();

    JTransfo jTransfo = new JTransfoImpl();

    for (TestDo t : list) {
        TestTo test = jTransfo.convert(t, new TestToImpl());

        to.add(test);
    }

    return to;
}
```

Is there a way to iterate the list with JTransfo, i. e. without a *for*?

Answer (score 0):

jTransfo has a convertList method you can use.

`jTransfo.convertList(list, TestToImpl.class);`